# How to interact with Remote Server using Python Sockets

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to connect to a server using python sockets. I am able to make a connection and fetch the response data. However, I want the socket communication to be interactive from the client side.

For instance, if I use netcat to connect to the server, the communication is interactive:

```
nc aa.bb.cc.dd 1234

Server greets you
I can enter the input here
Server responds to my input
```

However, when I make the connection using python sockets, all I receive is the greeting from the Server and program completes execution.

Here is the python code I am using:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import socket

host = "aa.bb.cc.dd"
port = 1234

remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((remote_ip, port))
print s.recv(1024)
```

I want to modify the above python program so that I can send inputs to the Server as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do

```
input_data = input("Enter something: ")
s.send(bytes(input_data,'utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while loop to get user input, send to server, and get a response continuously.

```
while True:
    print(str(s.receive(1024)))
    toSend = input()
    s.send(bytes(toSend, "utf-8"))
```